# Can I get the selected text in an email message in my Outlook 2013 Mail App?

Tags: office-2013

I am developing a Mail App for Office 2013, and I would really like to take an action when the user selects some text in the email message. This appears to be relatively trivial if I am creating a Task Pane app; I just add:

```
Office.context.document.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.DocumentSelectionChanged, handleSelectionChange);
```

and my `handleSelectionChange` function is called. However, in a Mail App, `document` is `undefined`, and the `mailbox` property of `context` does not have any event-related methods, at least according to the documentation that I have seen.

Is what I am seeking to do possible?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to speak with the Lead Project Manager about this, and it turns out that this feature is not available in the current release of the Office 2013 API. He did agree that it would make for some interesting possibilities, but that's all. I hope to see it in a future version of the API some day.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late but the link below shows how to get selected text from an email message (body) via ActiveExplorer method. Hope it helps.

[Get Selected Text from Outlook Mailitem using ActiveExplorer (not ActiveInspector)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28151297/get-selected-text-from-outlook-mailitem-using-activeexplorer-not-activeinspecto#new-answer)

Comment: Please add the relevant steps from the link to your answer.