# Get Selected Text from preview pane using ActiveExplorer (not ActiveInspector)

Tags: vba, outlook

Is it possible to get selected text using ActiveExplorer?

All code I've seen uses the ActiveInspector. I need to use ActiveExplorer, aka preview pane.

I tried

```
GMID = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following (which uses Inspector) still works for the preview pane:

```
set item =  Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
MsgBox item.GetInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection.Text
```

Or you can use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author), which explicitly exposes the preview pane through the [SafeExplorer](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/SafeExplorer.htm) object (which also exposes the ribbon and a few other goodies):

```
set sExplorer = CreateObject("Redemption.SafeExplorer")
sExplorer.Item = Application.ActiveExplorer
MsgBox sExplorer.ReadingPane.SelText
```

**Update 1/1/2021** - the latest versions of Outlook (2016 and 2019) expose `Explorer.PreviewPane` property, which can be used as

```
MsgBox Application.ActiveExplorer.PreviewPane.WordEditor.Application.Selection.Text
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an application where I retrieve several elements from the most recent message in the preview pane or popped out message.

```
'
' Check if Outlook is running
If Not Process.GetProcessesByName("OutLook").Length < 1 Then
    Dim app As Outlook.Application = TryCast(GetObject(, "Outlook.Application"), Outlook.Application)
    '
    ' Get last opened/previewed message
    If Not app.ActiveExplorer Is Nothing Then
        Dim message As Outlook.MailItem = TryCast(app.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1), Outlook.MailItem)
        If Not message Is Nothing Then
            '
            ' Sample of exposed elements
            Dim MailTo As String = message.Body
            Dim CopyTo As String = message.CC
            Dim BlindCopyTo As String = message.BCC
            Dim Content As String = message.Body
            Dim SendTime As Date = message.RecievedTime
            Dim SentFrom As String = message.SenderEmailAddress
        End If
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the following example:

```
Sub GetSelectedItems()
        Dim myOlApp As New Outlook.Application
        Dim myOlExp As Outlook.Explorer
        Dim myOlSel As Outlook.Selection
        Dim MsgTxt As String
        Dim x As Integer
        MsgTxt = "You have selected items from: "
        Set myOlExp = myOlApp.ActiveExplorer
        Set myOlSel = myOlExp.Selection
        For x = 1 To myOlSel.Count
            MsgTxt = MsgTxt & myOlSel.Item(x).SenderName & ";"
        Next x
        MsgBox MsgTxt
    End Sub
```

Apparently, you need to create an instance of explorer before asking it to return the topmost item.

Link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa219397%28v=office.11%29.aspx

Comment: How does this get the selected text?